# Django positional/keyword argument issue in form

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm getting a `__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'school'` error when trying to submit a form. There's something hinky with the arguments, but I can't quite nail it down.

view:

```
if "AddCourse" in request.POST: #"AddCourse" is the name of the submit button in the template
        f = CourseAddForm(request.POST, prefix='crs')#, school=this_school) #use Instance to edit previous stuff
        g = SectionAddwCourseForm(request.POST, prefix='sctn', school=this_school)
        if f.is_valid() and g.is_valid():
            new_course = f.save()
            new_section = g.save(commit=False)
            new_section.course = new_course
            new_section.save()
            g.save_m2m()
            s=Scollection.objects.create(Name="All Standards",Active=True,course=new_course)
        else:
            print 'invalid'
```

form:

```
class SectionAddwCourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = ['Name','teacher']
        labels = {
        "Name":"Section Name",
        }
    def __init__(self, school, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SectionAddwCourseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print school
        try:
            #self.fields['standards'].queryset = self.instance.standards.all() #works to get current ass't stds
            self.fields['teacher'].queryset = Teacher.objects.filter(school=school).order_by('LastName')
        except:
            print "except teacher list for this school"
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you call

```
SectionAddwCourseForm(request.POST, prefix='sctn', school=this_school)
```

the request.POST will correspond to the first parameter of `SectionAddwCourseForm.__init__` after `self`, so `school`. And you pass another parameter with keyword `school` so there is multiple values for that.
Order of parameters is very important!

Comment: What's the solution for that issue, then?

Comment: well, it's to put the your parameters in the order expected by you function. so school first.

Comment: It's still the same error message ? I guess you have a `school` in request.POST too. You need to remove it.

Comment: It's that there's a keyword arg before a positional one issue now.

Comment: ok so just pass the value for the school parameter, without `school=`

Comment: Then getting it out was an issue of adding `school = kwargs.pop('school')` before the `super`